# Parameter not Found Error in RDLC Report

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, rdlc

I am trying to send parameters to RDLC Report but it is not working. A detail screen shots are given below. Kindly Help.

> Parameters in RDLC Report

[image]

> Coding
>   [image]
>
> Error

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the properties of OPBALANCE?? Is your report working without the params - i mean only report without the parameters??

Comment: The report doesnot work without parameters. It gives error. I have tried to set the default values but still the parameters are not passing.

Comment: Can you share the rdlc code??

Comment: Code of calling rdlc is already shared.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
            ReportParameterCollection reportParameters = new ReportParameterCollection();
            reportParameters.Add(new ReportParameter("OPBALANCE", "Some value"));
            reportViewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(reportParameters);
```